# making a file only writable and visible from a script

Tags: bash, file-permissions

I want to index some files and keep a registry as part of a utility I am writing in BASH. So, my tool would go to a massive directory and write some essential information about each file it finds there to another file that I would like to call "myregistry." The file would only be rewritten if the user asks it to - since going through a large file structure and "indexing" it this way would take considerable time.

I want this file to not show up when the user does `ls` in the directory where it is contained. In addition, I want the user to have no privileges with it at all - the user should not be able to open it up on `vim` or anything, not even to just look at it.

However, if the user executes my script again, I want the user to have the option of getting some information out of the file from there. I also want the script to have the permissions to look at the file and add or delete things from it, if the user prompts it to. But the user should not be able to do anything to it directly.

How can I do this? It would require using `chmod` but I have no idea how to put it together.

I'm thinking:

```
# Enable write permission
# Do Something - ensure that no one else is writing to this file
# Disable write permission
```

Comment: If you want the script to be able to access the file when `user1` executes the script, then the file must be readable by `user1`. If you want to be able to add and remove readability, then the file must be **owned** by `user1`. What is in your registry that is so secret?

Comment: A dedicated user and a sticky-permission-ed script might be an option too but I'm not sure that actually works.

Comment: @glennjackman I could make it readable. That wouldn't be so problematic. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this work?  write_index and read_index are your work.

```
cd massive_dir
TFILE=$(mktemp --tmpdir=.)
write_index >$TFILE
mv -f $TFILE .index
chmod a-rw .index
```

To read

```
chmod +r .index
read_index .index
chmod -r .index
```

Note that no locking is needed because of the temp file.  mv is atomic.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, you're more or less on an equal footing with other processes that run under the same user. Whatever you can do, they can do. If you can hide and unhide something, so can they. Interpreted scripts need read permissions to run, so it's not like you can hide any secrets in your executable. If you can however, distribute your software as a binary, you'll be able to run without being readable. Then you can hardcode a secret into the binary and use it to encrypt and decrypt files. Users will be able to run your binary, but only the superuser will be able to get the secret and decrypt your registry. That's real security (against regular (nonroot) users) (especially if you manage to create and embed the secret at installation time).

Playing with dotfiles and permissions won't fool any advanced user.